# Un-able to connect with my the Local Database in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

When I tried to connect with my **Remote Database, I was able to connect susccesfully**. But when **I tried to connect to my local database, I was un-able to connect**. I am curious to know about this Because I dont have any issues in connecting with the remote database.

I appreciate your kind help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: >>I was un-able to connect<< Is there any error message?

Comment: Yes. Provider: Named Pipes Provider, Error - 40 Could not open connection to SQL Server

Comment: Is the server running?

Comment: Can you show us the connection string you use for the local database ? Usualy the server is ./SQLEXPRESS

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. Server is running. I was able to connect with the remote database. I am using the GUI  to connect - Just the machine name.

Answer (score 0):

Run SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Under your native client options you'll have "Client Protocols".

Make sure that "Named Pipes" is enabled on all of these.